# PhpStorm ignores the "Root path" server setting at "Start SSH session..."

Tags: ssh, terminal, phpstorm

How can I `Start SSH session...` in a custom directory or in `Root path` directory in PhpStorm?

PhpStorm ignores the `Root path` server setting at `Start SSH session...`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `Root Path` setting is working only for deployment (or `Browse remote host`), not for `Start SSH Session...` option.

Here is the YouTrack ticket about it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-11878

Please feel free to vote & subscribe.